# What is #pragma once used for?

Tags: c++

Can anyone help me understand #pragma?

```
ifndef TARGET_OS_LINUX
#pragma once
endif
```

What,when, where, why, an example?

The above is in some code that I am refactoring....

Answer (score 48, accepted):

`#pragma` is just the prefix for a compiler-specific feature.

In this case, `#pragma once` means that this header file will only ever be included once in a specific destination file. It removes the need for [include guards](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Include_guard).

Comment: etherything is right except warning that #pragmas are compiler extensions, they are not in Standard. You better avoid them.

Comment: isn't that what he said? Compiler-specific feature == non-standard compiler extension

Comment: @John - So where can I get a list of compiler specific features that I can use? These change depending upon GCC and Intel CC I am sure, so what is the best safe guard for portable code?

Comment: Get the list of compiler specific pragmas? - in your compilers documentation.  Best safe guard for portable code?  Don't use #pragma.

Comment: Included in this answer should be what the word "pragma" actually stands for or is short for!

Answer (score 17):

- What -- it is header guard. This file will be included only once.
- When -- at a compile process
- why -- to avoid  double including.

"Header guards are little pieces of code that protect the contents of a header file from being included more than once."

Answer (score 0):

GCC's official documentation states: https://gcc.gnu.org/onlinedocs/cpp/Pragmas.html:

> `#pragma once`
>
> If `#pragma once` is seen when scanning a header file, that file will never be read again, no matter what. It is a less-portable alternative to using `#ifndef` to guard the contents of header files against multiple inclusions.

See also my answer here: [`#ifndef` syntax for include guards in C++](https://stackoverflow.com/a/77719024/4561887).