# C++ header file: error: expected unqualified-id before ')' token

Tags: c++, header-files

Sorry for asking such a beginner question, but I'm stuck writing header files. For information, there aren't StackOverflow articles relating to the problem I have -- it seems like I've got a very simple setting wrong but couldn't find it on the internet.

Error message:

```
insertion/insertion.h:16:24: error: expected unqualified-id before ')' token   
   16 |         void insertion();
```

insertion.cpp:

```cpp
#include <insertion.h>
// more imports

void insertion() {
    // implementation not shown
}

int main() {
    insertion();
    return 0;
}
```

insertion.h:

```cpp
#include <iostream>
// exactly the same imports as the file above but didn't import itself

#ifndef insertion
#define insertion

class Insertion {
    public:
        void insertion();
};

#endif
```

execute.cpp:

```cpp
#include "insertion/insertion.h"
using namespace std;

int main() {
    // still writing
}
```

The file structure looks like this:

```
|- execute.cpp
|- insertion\
|---- insertion.cpp
|---- insertion.h
```

Any help is greatly appreciated.

Comment: `#define insertion` - what do you think that does to `void insertion();` in your class decl ?  Result: `void ();` . Pick a proper include-guard name (and unrelated, headers included in headers should be fenced into the same include guards).

Comment: ot: the includes should be inside the header guards, `void insertion() {...}` is not a definition for `void Insertion::insertion()` and there can be only one `main`, though none of this is directly related to the error message

Comment: If you mean for `insertion()` to be a class constructor, then note it needs the same capitization as the class name.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

`#define insertion` colides with `void insertion();`.

Change

```
#ifndef insertion
#define insertion
```

to

```
#ifndef _insertion_h_inc_
#define _insertion_h_inc_
```

Or better: change

```
#include <iostream>
// exactly the same imports as the file above but didn't import itself

#ifndef insertion
#define insertion

class Insertion {
    public:
        void insertion();
};

#endif
```

to

```
#ifndef _insertion_h_inc_
#define _insertion_h_inc_

#include <iostream>
// exactly the same imports as the file above but didn't import itself

class Insertion {
    public:
        void insertion();
};

#endif
```

Comment: How should I include this `.h` file then? Do I still use `#include <insertion.h>` or `#include <_insertion_h_inc_.h>` or neither? The file is still named `insertion.h`, for your information

Comment: Almost: _"...the identifiers that begin with an underscore are reserved in the global namespace...."_  https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/identifiers

Comment: @crimsonpython24 the names of the header guards can be anything. They should be unique and not collide with names you use in your code

Comment: Just keep `#include <insertion.h>`- Don't mix up file names and preprocessor symbols

Comment: Get it, thanks for your help! (will accept after six minutes, cooldown not there yet)

Answer (score 2):

The line

```
#define insertion
```

is the cause of your problems.

`insertion` is replaced by an empty token in all the places after that.

---

```
class Insertion {
    public:
        void insertion();
};
```

becomes

```
class Insertion {
    public:
        void ();
};
```

and

```
void insertion() {
    // implementation not shown
}

int main() {
    insertion();
    return 0;
}
```

becomes

```
void () {
    // implementation not shown
}

int main() {
    ();
    return 0;
}
```

---

Now you can see why your program fails to compile.

Change

```
#ifndef insertion
#define insertion
```

to

```
#ifndef insertion_h
#define insertion_h
```

That should resolve your problems.

---

Better still, use `#pragma once`. Most modern compilers support it.

```
#pragma once

#include <iostream>

class Insertion {
    public:
        void insertion();
};
```

Comment: Get it, thanks for your help!

Answer (score 1):

I always do this on my codes

insertion.h

```
#pragma once
#ifndef insertion_h
#define insertion_h
//some codes goes here
#endif
```

in my main.cpp file

```
#include "insertion.h"
```

and you're good to go, hope this helps.

Regards,

Joey

**EDIT:**
if you want to learn more about pragma you may refer to this link here [more on pragma's](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5776910/what-does-pragma-once-mean-in-c)

Comment: Get it, thanks for your help!

Comment: my answer is a direct approach, though other answers that were provided also work.