# Why there set macro definition and namespace in C++ .h file?

Tags: c++

I am reading this [open source project](https://github.com/shekyan/slowhttptest/blob/master/src/range-request-generator.h):

I have two questions:

1. I found the

```
#ifndef _RANGE_REQUEST_GENERATOR_H_
#define _RANGE_REQUEST_GENERATOR_H_
#endif
```

and I only find the `_RANGE_REQUEST_GENERATOR_H_` in this .h file, other place not use it.

so, what's the usage of the macro definition?

2. there use the namespace wrap the functions.

```
namespace slowhttptest {
    //functions
}
```

what's the purpose? why do not use `std`, is it better?

Comment: For the first, look for the term "header include guard" - it's a technique to protect from problems that arise if a header file is included more than once (e.g. if a source file includes multiple headers, and more than one of them include this one).    For the second, declaring or defining functions in namespace `std` is generally not allowed by the standard (only an implementation of the standard library can do that).

Comment: Also useful read: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1263521/what-is-pragma-used-for

Comment: And Read https://stackoverflow.com/questions/47830610/what-are-the-dangers-of-using-pragma-once

Answer (score 1, accepted):

#### Question #1

See [Purpose of Header guards](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2979384/purpose-of-header-guards)

#### Question #2

Consider the case where you are using libraries. And two libraries would both like to have a function named `Push()`. We could name them: `LibraryFoo_Push()`, and `LibraryBar_Push()`, or we could use namespaces. Namespaces have some additional benefits with lookups as well.

And see [C++ When is it OK to extend the `std` namespace?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/41062294/c-when-is-it-ok-to-extend-the-std-namespace) for when you are allowed to add stuff to the `std` namespace.